# Unreachable code detected in while loop

Tags: c#

I have the code below:

```
   public static int Number()
    {
        bool done = false;
        while (done == false)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] numbers = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
                int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(numbers[x]);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return x;
                done = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("can't");
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the error:

> unreachable code detected at 'done = true;'.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the catch statement but why is that? I can't work out the error here.

Comment: has nothing to do with the `catch`. It is because of the `return` that is written just before it.

Comment: Why is there a while loop at all if you want to both return _and_ set it to 'done' in the first iteration?

Answer (score 1):

The line following your `return` cannot be reached. See comment in code:

```
public static int Number()
{
    bool done = false;
    while (done == false)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] numbers = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
            int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[x]);
            Console.ReadLine();
            return x;  //THIS IS PREVENTING THE NEXT LINE
            done = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("can't");
        }
    }
}
```

> The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it
>   appears and returns control to the calling method. It can also return
>   an optional value.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to return outside the while loop after the loop exits instead of returning from within the `while` loop, as soon as `while` loop breaks it would return the value hold by `x`:

```
public static int Number()
{
    bool done = false;
    int x = 0;
    while (done == false)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] numbers = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
            x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[x]);
            Console.ReadLine();

            done = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("can't");
        }

    }
    return x;
}
```

another suggestion is that you can simplify your `while` loop condition like:

```
while (!done)
{
   // code goes here 
}
```

Comment: This is a more complete answer. Good form.

Comment: Actually, this code just makes it return from the first loop... making the whole loop useless. I rather think the original question is missing an "if" that checks if the input is a specific value... but then that check should be before the potential exceptions at the parse and the array accessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reach a line after `return`.

In your case this line:

```
Console.ReadLine();
return x; <---
done = true;
```